# How to load a dataframe based on a csv file name containing timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, csv, timestamp

I believe that my problem is really straightforward and there must be a really easy way to solve this issue, however as I am quite new with Python, specially pandas, I could not sort it out by my own.

I have **hundreds** of csv files that are on the following format: `text_YYYY-mm-dd_HH-MM-SS.csv`, each csv comprehends one hour of data.

I want to be able to acess the csv files based on two variables, which are named `startTime` and `EndTime`, and then, I want to gather all the files that are in between these dates into one dataframe. As I have hundreds of dataframes, concatenating all into a huge dataframe and then filtering is not an option.

So, for example, if I set `startTime = 2019-10-16 7:00:00` and `EndTime = 2019-10-16 09:00:00`, then, I want to gather all the csv files that comprehends the data in between that time interval into one dataframe. Therefore, taking just the csv files `text_2019-10-16_7:00:00`, `text_2019-10-16_8:00:00`  and `text_2019-10-16_9:00:00` into one dataframe.

Hope that I managed to be succinct and precise. I would really appreciate your help on this one! Suggestions of what to look up for are also welcome

Comment: if startTime is string, then convert it to DateTime, then extract all relevant fields, for example, year, month, day, etc. and create the required name for CSV file. You can use datetime.strptime() function from the datetime module to convert the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop by list of filenames and filter datetimes between start and end, then create DataFrame by [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), append to `list` called `out` and last use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
startTime = '2019-10-16 7:00:00'
EndTime = '2019-10-16 09:00:00'


files = ['text_2019-10-16_7:00:00.csv',
         'text_2019-10-16_8:00:00.csv',
         'text_2019-10-16_9:00:00.csv',
         'text_2019-10-16_19:00:00.csv']

startTime = pd.to_datetime(startTime)
EndTime = pd.to_datetime(EndTime)

out = []
for x in files:
    date = pd.to_datetime(x.split('_', 1)[1].split(.)[0], format='%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')
    if date >= startTime and date <= EndTime:
        out.append(pd.read_csv(x))

df = pd.concat(out, ignore_index)
```

Or:

```
from datetime import datetime

startTime = datetime.strptime(startTime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
EndTime = datetime.strptime(EndTime, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

out = []
for x in files:
    date = datetime.strptime(x.split('_', 1)[1].split(.)[0],, '%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S')
    if date >= startTime and date <= EndTime:
        out.append(pd.read_csv(x))

df = pd.concat(out, ignore_index)
```